# Full list of $A_5$ subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Can you please list all of the $H$ such that $H<A_5$?

I know that $A_4$ has following subgroups:

-one trivial subgroup (every group has it)

-the full $A_4$

-the normal Klein four group

-four cyclic subgroups of order $3$

-three cyclic subgroups of order $2$.

But $A_5$ clearly has a more complicated subgroup structure...

Comment: http://schmidt.nuigalway.ie/subgroups/a5.pdf

Comment: see [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A5).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are:

-one trivial subgroup

-$15$ cyclic subgroups of order $2$ generated by double transpositions

-$5$ Klein four groups generated by pairs of double transpositions, $10$ cyclic subgroups of order $3$ generated by $3$-cycles

-$10$ subgroups isomorphic to $S_3$ generated by a $3$-cycle and a double transposition

-$5$ subgroups isomorphic to $A_4$

-$6$ subgroups isomorphic to $C_5$

-$6$ subgroups isomorphic to $D_5$

-the whole group

Total $59$ subgroups.